# How to set keep alive interval for HTTP connection in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

Http transport channel in WCF uses persistent HTTP connections by default. How to control keep alive timeout for those connections? Default value is 100s. I found that value by monitoring application in Procmon. I haven't found any setting in http transport binding element which configures this timeout. Is there any .NET class which can control that timeout?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080721055556/http://blog.magenic.com/blogs/jons/archive/2007/05/04/The-Tao-of-Microsoft-WCF-CustomBinding-Configuration-Elements.aspx

There is a detailed discussion of manipulating the keep alive property during an http connection.

Comment: Thanks for post but this doesn't answer the question. Question is not about turning off keep alive but about setting keep alive timeout. So I want to have keep alive turn on and I want to control its duration.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this. The problem is that the underlying kernel http.sys has it's own timeout and it will break the connection.

```
http://mmmreddy.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/wcf-use-of-http-transport-sharing-persistent-tcp-sessions/

netsh http add timeout timeouttype=idleconnectiontimeout value=120
```

Also, this question is similar to this [What 130 second timeout is killig my WCF streaming service call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266854/what-130-second-timeout-is-killig-my-wcf-streaming-service-call)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're wanting to adjust the `Keep-Alive` HTTP header.  You should read [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20110605181241/http://www.io.com/~maus/HttpKeepAlive.html) on HTTP keep-alive and first determine if this is really something worth your time.

If it is, try creating a [Message Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector.aspx).  This should allow you to modify the HTTP headers for each message that gets sent out:

```
public class KeepAliveMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    // ...

    public object BeforeSendRequest(
        ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,
        System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        // Add/modify the Keep-Alive header
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "9000");
        request.Properties.Add(
            HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
        return null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This idea is interesting. I saw something like that in communication with Cassini but I think it is not standard header. Anyway I will try it during next few days. If it works I will set the new bounty and award you.

Comment: Btw. I don't need to use it. I just want to know if it is possible to change it somehow and where the default value 100s comes from.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka : Sorry to burry out this old post, but have you been able to set or read this HTTP keep-alive value. If yes, I would be very interested in knowing more about it. Thanks

Comment: https://www.io.com/~maus/HttpKeepAlive.html not found ***404 error***, _url broken_

Answer (score 1):

Setting ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime should let you change the default 100 second idle timeout on the persistent HTTP connections.

https://www.visualbasicplanet.info/windows-communication/configuring-http-connections.html

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466490/how-to-set-keep-alive-interval-for-http-connection-in-wcf/3543894#3543894), and what I can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.aspx), it looks like you want to create a custom http binding, and set the `inactivityTimeout` attribute.

From the MSDN article:

> ```
> <bindings>
>   <customBinding>
>     <binding name="Binding1">
>       <reliableSession acknowledgementInterval="00:00:00.2000000" enableFlowControl="true"
>                         maxTransferWindowSize="32" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" maxPendingChannels="128"
>                         maxRetryCount="8" ordered="true" />
>       <security mode="None"/>
>       <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
>                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
>                     proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" 
>                     useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
>     </binding>
>   </customBinding>
> </bindings>
> ```

Comment: No. I want to set HTTP keep alive not Reliable session keep alive. HTTP keep alive is described in HTTP protocol specification.

Comment: Seems like HTTP connections should always be persistent, as per RFC 2616 (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.1).

Comment: I don't think so. The RFC says that HTTP implementation should implement HTTP persistent connections. Not that only persistent connection should be used.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Seems it may be a function of your IIS Server and nothing to do with the WCF service?  I know this link applies to IIS6, but maybe it serves as a foundation to something similar in IIS7?
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/73566f83-c257-4941-8ed8-7ae45b2e7985.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I have already tryed to set up connection timeout on IIS and it didn't work. It is not related to keep alive setting. Anyway I will try it again during next few days. If it works I will set the new bounty and award you.