# System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: the request was cancelled

Tags: .net, wcf, system.net.webexception, service-reference, communicationexception

I have a WCF service that has been giving me this error under load conditions (and I can't seem to recreate the error otherwise). We've been trying to find a way around it for about a week now with no such luck..

The error I see has two parts to it,

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   An error: (The request was aborted:
>   the request was cancelled.) occurred
>   while transmitting data over the http
>   channel.

and:

> System.Net.WebException: The request
>   was aborted: the request was
>   cancelled.

I've seen many people suggest to disable working with keep alive by overloading a method in the `Reference.cs` file and setting `KeepAlive = false`, however, our client side is using a service reference (in addition to web reference) and this option does not exist anymore.

Another option I've seen was to add a custom Binding to the service instead of the `BasicHttpBinding` we are using now, but that would bother backwards support of the webservice to those who have been using a webReference (since `CustomBinding` is not SOAP enabled).

Has anyone dealt with this error before? Is there a way to disable keep alive in WCF without affecting the server side? Is there anything other that keep alive that is known to cause this error?

Comment: You can access Http Context and do what you want. Have a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/justinjsmith/archive/2007/08/22/setting-http-headers-in-wcf-net-3-5.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that HTTP keep alive is responsible for this. WCF should be able to handle this by itself so the HTTP persistant connection is shared among requests and if it expires (it expires after [100s of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466490/how-to-set-keep-alive-interval-for-http-connection-in-wcf)) WCF creates new one without firing any exception. If your connection is aborted during request transmission then I expect there will be some other problem.

You can use this custom binding as equivalent to BasicHttpBinding without HTTP keep alive:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="NoKeepAlive">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Yes, it is responsible and I have seen it before.

Comment: Wow, I just experienced this myself. What a surprise. Thanks, @Aliostad

Comment: @Aliostad Just out of curiosity, are you also calling a Tomcat-based Java web service?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when trying to upload large files.  I had to add this to the web.config of the web services

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem.
In my case I was executing requests ASynchronously. I was sending a few hundred requests to the 'server' from my client. I am/was using basicHttpBinding. And in my app.config setting the  openTimeout property was set to 60 seconds or one minute. Once I set that to a bigger number like 10 minutes, the problem has gone away.

So for instance I changed all these values in my app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IScriptRunHost" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                    openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
```

to 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be caused by mixing `using` clauses with asynchronous calls to WCF services.

For example:

```
using (ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient(proxyName)) {
  proxy.Open();
  return proxy.FunctionCallAsync(parameters); //Return type being Task<ResultSet>
}
```

This will trigger a race condition between how fast can it dispose of `proxy` versus how fast the asynchronous `Task<ResultSet>` can be completed. Longer the task takes the more likely it will be to end up in a Faulted state and the Result containing a System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException.

This can be fixed by removing the using clause:

```
ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient(proxyName))
proxy.Open();
return proxy.FunctionCallAsync(parameters); //Return type being Task<ResultSet>
```

Note that `proxy` should be persisted too so that once the asynchronous call is completed that a `proxy.Close()` can be done.

Comment: This was helpful for my issue as well, which was a bit different: if your OperationContract returns Task<...> (as in `Task<Foo> LoadFoo();`), the issue is similar, disposing of the proxy beats resolving the Task to get reponse data. Bad API, yes, but that's what I have.

Comment: I would advise to fix the race condition by simply awaiting the `proxy.FunctionCallAsync`. Not awaiting async code inside a using can produce all kinds of undefined behavior and should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

add this in app.config

```
 <system.net>
 <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="5"/>
                <add address="https://api.limitedconnections.com*" maxconnection="2"/>                
                <add address="https://api.moreconnections.com*" maxconnection = "10"/>
        </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Refer the below link

https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2019/12/02/configuring-maxconnection-in-biztalk/