# Calling a webservice from a web api project throws "Request was aborted..."-error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a datalayer where I'm connecting to a webservice.

When I'm calling this webservice via the datalayer from a test project, it is successful every time.

When running a Web Api project (in VS) with the same configuration as the test project, an error occur when calling the same function: 
 - "An error (The request was aborted: The request was canceled.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel."

Any ideas what I could be forgetting?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900040/system-net-webexception-the-request-was-aborted-the-request-was-cancelled ?