# HTTP Keep-alive and ServiceHost / C#?

Tags: wcf

How can I enable/disable the HTTP Keep-alive and set the connection timeout of a self hosted service using the application configuration and the C# ServiceHost?

For example,

```
MyService service = new MyService();
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service);
serviceHost.Open();
```

What do I have to put in the application configuration to set the http keep alive and timeout.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:9005/"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="IMyService"
          behaviorConfiguration="myServerEndpointBehavior"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <!-- WHERE TO ENABLE/DISABLE http keep alive and timeout -->
</configuration>
```

The settings under IIS are found if you go to the IIS Manager.  Right click on the "Default Web Site"->Properties->Web Site->Connections.  Can I do that through the system.serviceModel configuration?

Comment: I solved this, see here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266854/what-130-second-timeout-is-killig-my-wcf-streaming-service-call

Answer (score 2):

Keep alive for http connections is turned on by default. If you want to turn it off you must create custom binding:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpWithoutKeepAlive">
            <webMessageEncoding />
            <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:9005/"
          binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WebHttpWithoutKeepAlive"
          contract="IMyService"
          behaviorConfiguration="myServerEndpointBehavior"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

[How to set a keep-alive timout is a mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466490/how-to-set-keep-alive-interval-for-http-connection-in-wcf). There is no "service timeout" in your scenario (it makes sense only in bindings with session) and keep-alive timeout doesn't abort communication between client and service.

Btw. your example code defines service as singleton object.