# WCF & keepAliveEnabled - More than two sockets at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, keep-alive

I try to make a multiple-thread requester in order to test answer time of my server.

My server is a WCF webservice, and my client has a service reference to this webservice.

WCF respect HTTP specifications, and I see on many websites WCF is Keep-Alive enabled by default. By only two connections from the same client are authorized at same time.

So, when I try to create 100 threads, only two of them are processing at the same time. So, after few loops, a lot of threads are in timeout.

I try to follow this article : [WCF wsHttpBinding with http keepalive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535074/wcf-wshttpbinding-with-http-keepalive/6535455#6535455) but it didn't work.

Here is my app config (modified by the Service Reference) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISabIn" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/SabIn.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISabIn" contract="TestWs.ISabIn"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ISabIn" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

I try to use customBinding in the appCode, like this article : [HTTP Keep-alive and ServiceHost / C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674171/http-keep-alive-and-servicehost-c)
but, when I execute my software, an erreor appears about "application/xml". If I try to translate in english, it would be somehting like "your client don't manage the application/xml message".

I need to do real-time transactions, and I can't if WCF only manage two sockets at same time...

Can you help me ?

PS : I can post the code of my client, but I'm not sure is useful since I know the problem is a sockets limitation.

SOLUTION (thnaks to Spender) : at the beginning of your code, change the default value (it is 2) in System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this caused by default .net limits on HTTP request to a single host? This is because [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defaults to 2.

When you issue an HTTP request, internally, a `ServicePoint` instance is created to manage the connections to a specific host. Make a new request to the same host, and it will use the same ServicePoint instance for connection management.

You can manipulate the limit for a single host with the following code:

```
var serviceUri = new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/SabIn.svc");
var servicePoint = System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(serviceUri);
servicePoint.ConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
```

I believe you can also [handle this in `web.config`/`app.config`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsk61s76%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I'm not sure if you can tweak limits associated with a single ServicePoint.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have I modify from the server, from the client or both ?

Comment: @BaptX : this would be a client setting.

Comment: I will test it tommorow in the morning (8 PM here). I will answer in few hours ;)

Comment: I'm not sure WCF use ServicePointManager... How retrieve it ?

Comment: @Baptx : I'm pretty sure that it does. I've added a namespace to my code example. What do you mean by "retrieve it"?

Comment: The solution is to change value in System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit - It was a misunderstanding - THANKS :)